# У тебя есть что-то(,) что поделать?

Tags: запятые

Нужна здесь запятая?

> Сегодня у меня нет ничего(,)что поделать.

> У тебя есть что-то(,) что поделать?

Comment: Говорите по-русски. Сегодня у меня есть чем заняться. Сегодня мне нечем заняться.  Или учите фразеологию русского языка, если  не знаете правильные  речевые обороты.

Comment: Пора родителей этого жолудя вызывать.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автору не нужны ответы. Развлекается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

(1) *Сегодня у меня нет **ничего, что** поделать.*

(2) *У тебя есть **что-то, что** поделать?*

**О грамматике** предложений (без стилистического разбора):

Эт  ***СПП*** с придаточными **местоименно-определительными**. **Местоименная** связь: указ. местоимение **ничего/что-то** — с.с. ***ЧТО***.

Придаточное предложение односоставное **инфинитивное.**

Answer (score 0):

Примеры употребления глагола ***поделать***:

(1) *Вот что **поделать**? Даже не знаю, заняться совершенно нечем. Письмо, что ли, кому написать?*

```
 Here's what to do? I don't even know, there's 
 absolutely nothing to do. Should I write a letter 
 to whom?
```

(2) *Вот что **поделать**, не замечает она меня! Разынтересовалась  мною! Еще одно письмо ей, что ли написать?*

```
 That's what to do, she doesn't notice me! She's 
 interested in me! Should I write her another 
 letter?
```

**ПОДЕЛАТЬ,** -аю, -аешь; св. что. 1. **Заняться** чем-л., делать что-л. в течение некоторого времени. П. гимнастику. П. опыты. 2. **Разг. Сделать последовательно одно за другим**; переделать. Все поделали двойные двери. 3. **Сделать, предпринять что-л.** в отношении кого-, чего-л.** Что я могу п.? Ничего не поделаешь; что поделаешь (о невозможности справиться, сладить с кем-, чем-л.). Поделка (см.).